# task output is missing in log file

Tags: ansible

playbook:

```yaml
- command: date
  register: date_output
- command: hostname
  register: hostname_output
- lineinfile:
    line: "{{inventory_hostname}} {{ item.cmd }}\n======================\n{{ item.stdout }}"
    path: /home/ubuntu/list.log
    create: yes
  with_items: 
    - "{{ date_output }}" 
    - "{{ hostname_output }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

playbook execution output:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [command] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.153.32]
changed: [192.168.153.31]

TASK [command] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.153.31]
changed: [192.168.153.32]

TASK [lineinfile] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.153.31 -> localhost] => (item={'delta': '0:00:00.001888', 'cmd': ['date'], 'rc': 0, 'stdout': 'Tue Jul  6 14:12:45 EDT 2021', 'end': '2021-07-06 14:12:45.780249', 'start': '2021-07-06 14:12:45.778361', 'changed': True, 'stderr': '', 'stdout_lines': ['Tue Jul  6 14:12:45 EDT 2021'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'ansible_facts': {'discovered_interpreter_python': '/usr/bin/python3'}, 'failed': False})
changed: [192.168.153.32 -> localhost] => (item={'changed': True, 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-07-06 14:12:45.842399', 'cmd': ['date'], 'stderr': '', 'end': '2021-07-06 14:12:45.844352', 'stdout': 'Tue Jul  6 14:12:45 EDT 2021', 'delta': '0:00:00.001953', 'stdout_lines': ['Tue Jul  6 14:12:45 EDT 2021'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'ansible_facts': {'discovered_interpreter_python': '/usr/bin/python3'}, 'failed': False})
changed: [192.168.153.31 -> localhost] => (item={'changed': True, 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'delta': '0:00:00.001809', 'cmd': ['hostname'], 'end': '2021-07-06 14:12:48.427204', 'stdout': 'ubuntu', 'start': '2021-07-06 14:12:48.425395', 'stdout_lines': ['ubuntu'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False})
changed: [192.168.153.32 -> localhost] => (item={'stderr': '', 'start': '2021-07-06 14:12:48.516075', 'delta': '0:00:00.001940', 'cmd': ['hostname'], 'rc': 0, 'changed': True, 'stdout': 'ubuntu1', 'end': '2021-07-06 14:12:48.518015', 'stdout_lines': ['ubuntu1'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False})

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.153.31             : ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
192.168.153.32             : ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Output of log file:

```
 cat /home/ubuntu/list.log
 192.168.153.31 ['date']
 ======================
 Tue Jul  6 14:12:45 EDT 2021
 192.168.153.31 ['hostname']
 ======================
 ubuntu
 192.168.153.32 ['hostname']
 ======================
 ubuntu1
```

I can see the `date` task output for `192.168.153.32` also writing to log file from `lineinfile` output. but it's missing in the log file.
when I do next iteration I can see different result:

```
cat /home/ubuntu/list.log
192.168.153.32 ['date']
======================
Tue Jul  6 15:52:32 EDT 2021
192.168.153.32 ['hostname']
======================
ubuntu1
192.168.153.31 ['hostname']
======================
ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is, that they are overwriting each others files, as ansible runs tasks in parallel. Use [throttle](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle) to limit it to running one task at a time:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item.cmd }}\n======================\n{{ item.stdout }}"
    path: /home/ubuntu/list.log
    create: yes
  with_items: 
    - "{{ date_output }}" 
    - "{{ hostname_output }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  throttle: 1
```

`throttle` was introduced with ansible 2.9

If you need to use an older version, you can either limit the number of forks to 1 using the `forks` option in `ansible.cfg` or adding `-f 1` to your `ansible-playbook` command.
Another option is to add `serial: 1` to your play (not task!) which will run each host after another.
Both of those options will increase the time your play needs to run.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html).

Comment: I can see ERROR! 'throttle' is not a valid attribute for a Task

Comment: In that case, your ansible version is too old. Please upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not allowed to upgrade... we have ansible 2.8

Comment: I added two more options to achieve serial processing to my answer

Comment: used serial:1  to solve the issue. since don't want to change the ansible.cfg. Thanks toydarian.